# Are Platform Events supported for Customer Community users?

Tags: apex, process-builder, customer-community, platform-event

I've got a very simple Platform event published by Apex code, and a subscribed Process Builder receiving it.

```
Transcript_Request__e patEvt = new Transcript_Request__e();
patEvt.Enrollment_Id__c = 'a0803004000VyFZAA5';
Database.SaveResult sr = EventBus.publish(patEvt);
```

Process Builder fired upon Platform event dispatch by Salesforce Internal user.

But when I dispatch Platform event as Community user, It doesn't seem to run.
I can see following success message in Community user debug log.

> 20:43:16.0
> (32893554)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[16]|sr|Database.SaveResult|true|false
> 20:43:16.0
> (32955631)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[16]|sr|{"success":true,"id":"e00xx0000000001AAA","errors":[{"status":"OPERATION_ENQUEUED","message":"7af7599b-04f9-49c3-8
> (16 more) ..."}]}|0x5fcca34d

And Database.SaveResult.Errors has one record with below:

> 20:43:16.0 (33820259)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[21]|err|"Error
> [statusCode=OPERATION_ENQUEUED, code=[xmlrpc=-1,
> statusCode=OPERATION_ENQUEUED, exceptionCode=null, scope=PublicApi,
> http=202], message=7af7599b-04f9-49c3-897a-dacf6bbc9c81,
> fields=null]"|0x206cef35

Seems we can't query EventBusSubscriber  as Communtiy, therefore I'm assuming we can't publish Platform events.

[image]

Any thoughts if Platform Events are supported for Customer Community or Customer Community Login users?

I couldn't find any [Docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_events.htm&type=5) which says it's not supported.

If not supported, is there any workarounds to use them in Community?
e.g. publish using apex, consume by Process Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform events are supported with community licenses, so I don't think this is your issue.

Could well be something else in the transaction that is causing the failure and rollback including the platform event. How are you triggering the platform event as a community user?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Andrew, It's the same Apex code simply called from a Aura component invoking AuraEnabled Apex method. I don't see process builder invoked in community user's debug logs. My colleague suggested me this could be because of https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnN8AAK.

Comment: Since you are using Platform Events rather than Push Topic Events, this shouldn't be the problem. We have community users creating platform events in our Org so am sure it's possible! Have you checked the community user's profile has Apex Class access? Does the class run without sharing? See if that helps.

Comment: I did debug the autoproc and it seems running. Thanks!, Noted we can't assign permission sets with VF page access to autoproc user. Therefore I had to go with scheduled batch where context user will have permission set with vf access.